# How can I tell when a given commit went into a branch?

Tags: git

I'm trying to find the origin of a bug in our code base. I have the SHA of a commit that I suspect caused the breakage, but I also know the date where the bug started to appear. I want to check when a given commit was merged into our main branch.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git bisect` should help you locate the bug quite nicely.

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git#Binary-Search

As for the commit SHA you are targeting, just run `git log` on it, and it will tell you all about the commit (date, author, etc.). Run `git log -p` on it to see what changes that commit made.

Comment: Awesome, went through the git book's overview of bisect and found the commit. Very cool

Answer (score 2):

```
git branch --contains SHA1
```

should print you all the branches which contain the given commit.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the suspect commit based on a date with:

```
git log --before=<date> -n 1
```

This, or something with a date a day or two before, could be the 'good' starting point for your `git bisect`.

Comment: I think this answer is best so far.  OP is not asking for the commit that *introduced* the bug - that is already known - but when that commit became part of the history of a particular branch.  This in combination with `git branch --contains` as the "test" for git-bisect could do it.  But is there a git one-liner for this too?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that your main branch is `master` and that the SHA you suspect is in `$SHA`.

First, find the merge commits that are in `master` but not in `$SHA`'s history:

```
$ git log --merges --oneline $SHA..master
```

Then, test each of these merge commits to determine which one contains `$SHA`. Let's assume a given merge commit ID is in `$MERGE`. You can list all of the commits that were merged into `master` by this commit with `git log --oneline $MERGE^..$MERGE`.

(This works because `$MERGE^` is the [first] parent of `$MERGE`, i.e. the snapshot of `master` before the merge, so `$MERGE^..$MERGE` is listing the commits in `$MERGE` but not in `$MERGE^`, i.e. the commits in `$MERGE` but not in `master` before the merge.)

Then you can `grep` for your target `$SHA`:

```
$ git log --oneline $MERGE^..$MERGE | grep ^$SHA
```

The first merge commit that gets any of its output past `grep` is your winner. Once you have identified the commit, you can `git show` it for more info.

```
$ git show $MERGE
```

I'd be interested in an easier way to do this, if anybody knows of one.